# MySQL Stored Procedure Loop

Tags: mysql

So I'm needing to pull 2 id fields from 2 different tables and insert them into a third table. This is for a permissions thing, so basically I need to get the `admin` table's id and loop that until all of the `building` table's ids are populated into the third table called `building_user`. This is to "start" the permissions table so I need every building ID to be matched up with every admin ID.

Here is what I'm trying and I can't quite figure it out, but I know I'm missing something.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE buildingUserAssignment()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE done2 INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE a, b INT;

   DECLARE admin CURSOR
   FOR
   SELECT id FROM admin;
   DECLARE building CURSOR
   FOR
   SELECT id FROM building;

   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done=1;


  OPEN admin;
  OPEN building;
  REPEAT
    FETCH admin into a;

    REPEAT
    FETCH building into b;
    INSERT INTO building_user VALUES (a,b);
    UNTIL done END REPEAT;

  UNTIL done END REPEAT;


  CLOSE admin;
  CLOSE building;
END;
```

I end up only getting one admin ID field (ID #2, even though there is a ID 1). Here is the sample databases:

`admin`:

```
SELECT id FROM admin;
1
2
3
5
6
7
9
11
```

`building`:

```
SELECT id FROM building;
0
1
3
6
7
8
10
```

Current End Result of invoking buildingUserAssignment:

```
SELECT * FROM building_user:
user_id building_id
2   0
2   1
2   2
2   3
2   4
2   4
3   4
5   4
6   4
7   4
9   4
11   4
```

So the building_user table should be something like this in the end, repeated of course for each admin id:

```
1 0
1 1
1 3
1 6
1 7
1 8
1 10
```

I'm sure its something stupid, but I think I've looked at it too long and now I'm stuck. I may not even be doing this the "best" way either, so I welcome any suggestions.

Comment: Really pointless to use a loop for this. Anyway, this question is confusing... how is the admin related to a building?

Comment: This is to "start" the permissions table so I need every building ID to be matched up with every admin ID.

Comment: `select into building_user user_id, building_id from building cross user` or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use loop. There is a type of join called [CROSS JOIN](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php) which produces a result set from number of rows from first table multiplied by the number of rows of the second table. And the resulting rows will be insert into `INSERT INTO..SELECT` syntax.

```
INSERT INTO building_user 
SELECT a.id, b.id
FROM admin a CROSS JOIN building_user b
```

Comment: Holy cow, that was about 2 million times easier! I'm new to messing with the DB directly so I didn't know about this. I could've written something in PHP but wanted to do it in the DB directly as I thought it would be best to start doing things there. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
WHILE i < v_count DO
    SET @start_date = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(v_current_item, '$.start_date'));
    SET @expiry_date = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(v_current_item, '$.expiry_date'));
    SET @amount = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(v_current_item, '$.amount'));
    SET @emp_id = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(v_current_item, '$.emp_id'));
    SET @update_id = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(v_current_item,'$.update_id'));
                    SET i := i + 1;

 END WHILE;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.